# Create EDMX from a custom Multiproject solution template

Tags: entity-framework, project-template

I'm trying to create a mulit-project (solution) custom template for the solution structure we use where I work.  This structure consists of a data project, which holds an .EDMX, a business library project to hold our entities and rules, and the WCF service project itself.  I can create the projects without a problem, but I'd like to be able open up the Entity Data Model Wizard, so that the user can set up the .EDMX as part of the execution of the template.  I've spent a couple hours on Google so far looking for a solution, and even opened up item template for the EDMX, and looked through the System.Data.Entity.Design dll in Reflector.  Is it as simple as adding the wizard element to my template, as is in the EDMX item template?  Or do I have to jump through other hoops?

Thanks in advance!